# Emulate or Open Android Backup Folder?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an "Android Backup" folder with some data inside. Is it possible to emulate this data on a virtual android/ AVD and if so will I be able to access the data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [Using the Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#sdcard)?

You can add any file to the sdcard of your emulated device using the terminal.

Edit: Actually the usage of the terminal can be found in the [Android Debug Bride](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#copyfiles) description.